# how to check if collection contains collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections `ProdList<Product, int>` and `RuleList<Product, int>` contains list of products and counts.

how do i get if RuleList all items partici in ProdList collection
I ve tried with

```
bool a= ProdList.All(x => RuleList.Contains(x));
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You should override the `Equals` method and then your code will work

Comment: What's ProdList and RuleList? Dictonaries i assume? Are you trying to match product or the int? or both?

Comment: @SledgeHammer both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the `Contains` method uses the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of the items, which if not overriden, are those of `object`.

Solutions:

1. Override your object's `Equals` and `GetHashCode`
2. Use `Any` instead of `Contains`:

   ```
   var result = ProdList.All(x => RuleList.Any(y => x.Product.Equals(y.Product) && 
                                                    x.IntValue == y.IntValue));
   ```
3. Implement a custom `IEqualityComparer` for your object's type

*Notice that in all these options you must also take care of comparing the `Product` class  (same 3 options are available)*